# MaterialEditText focus next EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Есть разметка страницы регистрации. Одно за другим идут поля Имя, Фамилия, Емейл, пароль, телефон. последние три имеют соответствубщий inputType. Больше разницы между ними нет. Нужно реализовать переход к следующему полю по Enter.

Так как последние гарантруют переход к следующему полю по enter, их не трогаю, на первые 2 EditText прикручиваю такой воt TextWatcher

```
private TextWatcher focusNext(final EditText current, final EditText next) {
        return new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                int index = s.length() - 1;
                if (index >= 0) {
                    char c = s.charAt(index);
                    if (c == '\n' || c == '\r') {
                        current.setText(current.getText().toString().replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), ""));
                        next.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Результат следующий - встаю на "ИМЯ" - enter переводит на "фамилия", вне зависимости от того, было ли что нибудь введено  поле или нет. Лайн.сепаратор валидно удаляется. Делаю то же действие на фамилии, Лайн.сепаратор удаляется, но фокус не просто уходит на Емейл, но тут же переходит на пароль.

Как можно решить такую проблему? И переход на следующий et по enter и инпут тайп нужны, может другим образом реализовать  TextWatcher?

Пытался добавить onKeyListener, но результат приблизительно такой же. По нажатию Enter KeyCode отлавливают сразу оба EditText, для которых установлен onKeyListener и фокус перемещается на Email, вне зависимости от того, с имени или с фамилии нажат Enter

Решил, добавив инпут тайп text к ET, без специализированного типа и убрав слушателей.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12566625/3212712) переход по `ENTER` к следующему `EditText` решается прописыванием следующего `EditText` в атрибутах разметки

```
android:nextFocusRight="@+id/EDITTEXT2"
```

Comment: Ваш Способ попробовал, у меня он не сработал, возможно потому что библиотека у меня сторонняя, хотя и полностью совместима с EditText. Я использую MaterialEditText от rengwuxian.

Comment: Не работает даже если убрать все повешенные вами слушатели?

Comment: мм, сейчас попробую. Работает если убрать инпуттайп. Но не хотелось бы от этого уходить

Comment: неа, без слушателей не работает

Comment: Если проблема только с `EditText` с `inputType = emailadress`, то может быть стоит попробовать *НЕ* вызывать `requestFocus` на его следующий `EditText` ?

Comment: Убрал инпу тайп с адреса, теперь проскакиает следующий EditText с инпут тайпом. И да, я убирал с них слушатели, это все равно происходит

Comment: Решил) Добавил инпут тайп - текст, к полям не имеющим спецтипа, и переход происходит автоматом без слушателей

Comment: Т.е. представленный мной способ работает только при условии наличия у всех `EditText` аттрибута `inputType`?

Comment: С этими et Ваш способ не работает вообще, мой , со слушателями, работает только при отсутствии input type

Comment: Хм...Ну, если у вас заработало - то опишите в ответе - кому-нибудь когда-нибудь это ещё пригодится.

Comment: Однозначно спасибо за участие :)